# workaround debian pin by architecture

Tags: apt

we can install packages for plural architectures on a debian system .

```
$ apt-config dump | grep Arch
APT::Architecture "mipsel";
APT::Architectures "";
APT::Architectures:: "mipsel";
APT::Architectures:: "amd64";
```

( in this situation , my native architecture is mipsel , and i also install packages for amd64 . i run them through qemu binfmt_misc . )

today i want to make the apt dependency resolution algorithm to pull packages for the native architecture whenever possible , and if there is no native choice , foreign .

the apt "Pin" mechanism is the obvious way to go . but [pinning by architecure is not implemented yet](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=687255) .

so i want to have a workaround solution for pinning by architecture .

---

even we have pinning by architecture , we still have to pay attention not to replace critical packages by packages for foreign architectures , which include the init , the shell , and the qemu .

Comment: "we still have to pay attention not to replace critical packages by packages for foreign architectures". Is that even possible. I think the architecture of multiarch makes it impossible. Would you care to outline a possible scenario?

Comment: the qemu binfmt is configured by a init script run during boot . anything before that should be native . one minute ago i checked out that aptitude refuses to replace dash , but says okay if i want to install an amd64 version of mount ( native being mipsel ) . @FaheemMitha

Comment: Interesting. Does that produce a functioning system? If not, it might be considered a bug.

Answer (score 2):

1. we can use different mirrors for different architecture .

   ```
   # /etc/apt/sources.list
   deb [ arch=mipsel ] http://1.mirror.debian.org stable main
   deb [ arch=amd64  ] http://2.mirror.debian.org stable main
   ```

   then configure pinning by origin .

   ```
   # /etc/apt/preferences
   Package: *
   Pin: origin "2.mirror.debian.org"
   Pin-Priority: /* some small number */
   ```
2. we can set up an alternative dns record pointing to the mirror . like amd64.mirror.my.own.domain cname 1.mirror.debian.org . sometimes the http server is sensitive for the host header . but it is possible that the server only checks for the suffix of the request domian name as if a.b.c is a legal host name , we may try access it by any.prefix.a.b.c .
3. we can set up a reverse proxy to the mirror .

Comment: i'm not sure what is the right priority to set . 100 seems to work in my situation .

Comment: anything 100<= P <500 should do, see `man apt_preferences`.