# APT version conflicts across different architectures even with Multi-Arch: same?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, multiarch, arm64

With Raspbian and a 64-bit kernel, I am fetching packages from the following sources:

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Attempting to install the minimal dependencies to run something like gzip:arm64 reports conflicts such as:

```
libgcc1 : Breaks: libgcc1:arm64 (!= 1:6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) but 1:6.3.0-18+deb9u1 is to be installed
gcc-6-base:arm64 : Breaks: gcc-6-base (!= 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) but 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1 is to be installed
```

It looks like the "+rpi1" *armhf* packages are conflicting with the non-rpi1 *arm64* packages. But that would mean that it's comparing package **versions** across two different architectures!

Error messages with apt-get can be misleading anyhow, so to bring my system into a state similar to bamarni's Debian Pi64 (where multiarch works), I can try downloading some non-rpi1 armhf packages from links such as https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/libgcc1/download Once I replace libgcc1:armhf, gcc-6-base:armhf, libc6:armhf, libatomic1:armhf and others, basic conflicts go away and I can install libgcc1:arm64 gcc-6-base:arm64 libc6:arm64 via apt. However, this isn't a great solution because in the process I have likely lost ARMv6 compatibility and other Raspbian-specific modifications.

And the above could still mean there's something else fishy hiding in the Raspbian packages. My next test is to use the Raspbian *.deb files, except with a script I repackage them to remove the `+rpi1` part of the version text in each control file. Once I do this and reinstall those packages, the conflicts with arm64 packages go away. This again indicates that APT is comparing package versions across two different architectures.

When I run `apt-cache show` on any of these they all say `Multi-Arch: same` with their correct corresponding `Architecture:` lines. As I understand things, it would only care about versions across different architectures in the cases of `Multi-Arch: foreign` or `Multi-Arch: allowed`.

What's going on here? It seems like APT is comparing package versions across different architectures when it shouldn't, which leads to bogus conflicts. I wonder if the fact that multiarch works okay on bamarni's Pi64 or Ubuntu MATE--or most i386+x86_64 systems--is in part luck that these systems have generally consistent package versions across 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [mandated by the multiarch specification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Architecture-independent_files_in_multiarch_packages):

> multiarch packages are required to be kept in lockstep; i.e., an implicit `Breaks: ${self}:other (!= ${binary:Version})`.

The reason is that packages always ship some arch-independent files in shared directories (`/usr/share/doc`), so the package management system has to ensure that they are identical across architectures. It does that by enforcing identical versions across architectures, even with binNMUs.

Inside a single distribution this isn’t much of a problem, but across distributions it is.

In your case specifically, let’s consider `gcc-6-base` (since that’s where the documentation lives). The Debian Stretch version installs its changelog in `/usr/share/doc/gcc-6-base/changelog.Debian.gz`. Installing the same package for other architectures, using the same version, installs the same file, so while technically there’s a conflict, it’s ignored. The Raspbian version however adds the following entry:

```
gcc-6 (6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) stretch-staging; urgency=medium

  [changes brought forward from 6.1.1-1+rpi1 by Peter Michael Green <plugwash@raspbian.org> at Wed, 11 May 2016 20:
  * Disable testsuite.

 -- Raspbian forward porter <root@raspbian.org>  Thu, 01 Mar 2018 00:03:02 +0000
```

Now the `/usr/share/doc/gcc-6-base/changelog.Debian.gz` is no longer identical. If we were to install both Debian Stretch and Raspbian Stretch versions of the package side-by-side, which version of the file should be kept? There’s no way to decide, so the packaging system forbids the situation entirely.

Comment: Awesome, super-thorough explanation all the way down to the changelog.Debian.gz diff in my test case packages.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. However, I'm interested in "fixing" this. While it totally makes sense to allow only one instance of a noarch-packge, I want to specify the origin (arch) of it. Some workarounds are shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183093/workaround-debian-pin-by-architecture), but is there anything better? Thanks.

Comment: @spawn you want to specify the arch of a noarch package? You’d be better off asking a new question, that way you can explain what you’re trying to do in more detail.

Comment: @StephenKitt I posted a new question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761286/apt-install-noarch-package-dependency-from-foreign-architecture). Thanks. Tycho.