# apt - install noarch package dependency from foreign architecture

Tags: debian, apt

Running Debian-11-amd64 on low-end devices I prefer installing the 32 bit version of the chromium browser to save some RAM (having called `dpkg --add-architecture i386`):

```
apt install chromium:i386
```

works fine. Now I also want to install the language pack, which is arch-independent:

```
$ apt install chromium-l10n
The following additional packages will be installed:
  chromium chromium-common chromium-sandbox
Suggested packages:
  chromium-shell chromium-driver
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chromium:i386 chromium-common:i386 chromium-driver:i386 chromium-sandbox:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium chromium-common chromium-l10n chromium-sandbox
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 4 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

So, apt wants to install the 64-bit package version, removing the 32-bit one. Not nice.

I tried

```
$ apt install chromium-l10n:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium-l10n:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromium-l10n:i386' has no installation candidate
```

and some pinning variants in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mychrome-i386`

```
Package: chromium-l10n
Pin: release o=security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_non-free_binary-i386_Packages
Pin-Priority: 900
```

which all didn't work. How can this be done (with reasonable effort)?

Thanks
Tycho

Comment: Did you try to set the pin priority of packages `chromium:i386`, `chromium-common:i386` and `chromium-sandbox:i386`? Did you try `apt install chromium:i386 chromium-l10n`?

Answer (score 1):

A more generic (than OP's) way to prevent reinstallation of the `amd64` variant with Pin prority is possible like this for example in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/local-chromium.pref` to be sure that the `amd64` version doesn't get reinstalled:

```
Package: chromium:amd64
Pin: origin *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

This won't change the priority of what is installable except it will prevent installing the `amd64` variant, leaving only the `i386` variant as a choice.

That's optional because this won't happen with the changes made below. A standard upgrade when discovering newer versions wouldn't do it with `apt upgrade` (but would probably do it with `apt full-upgrade`). Anyway expect all of this setup to clash one way or an other in the future when doing an actual upgrade from Debian n to Debian n+1: better then remove conflicting packages and reinstall them after the change of Debian release.

---

### `Multi-Arch: foreign`

The key element is to have a package that is in a different (foreign) architecture be considered as a native package by the dependency system. Obviously this should be done only when the actual package's behavior or API allows this.

Debian wiki's [Multiarch HOWTO tells](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Concepts):

> - If a package is marked 'Multi-Arch: foreign', then it can satisfy dependencies of a package of a different architecture (e.g 'debhelper:amd64' will satisfy a dependency on debhelper for any-architecture package).

Further references on Ubuntu's [MultiarchSpec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Binary_package_control_fields) (referenced by Debian in previous link):

> `Multi-Arch: foreign`
>
> - The package is **not** co-installable and **should** be allowed to satisfy the dependencies of a package of another architecture than its own.
>
> [...]

I used to do what OP did with Firefox for the same reasons: sparing memory on a low-end system. The change has to be done in the "main" binary package, not in the packages that depends on it. Also as the package is changed, when keeping the same version, the dependency algorithm will prefer the repository source to the installed source, but won't do it for dependency reasons. It will just always write the package was kept and it won't be easily visible if the package is kept because there's a new version available but not installable, or because there's *the same* version available. This can be worked around by slightly increasing the package version.

This method works fine on some packages (including `chromium`, `firefox-esr` and `thunderbird`) but might fail on others especially if they depend on non-library packages having themselves the same kind of problem, or libraries that weren't adapted properly for Multiarch (arguably a bug: one should expect runtime libraries to be `Multi-Arch: same` and co-installable).

The goal is to:

- set the package as `Multi-Arch: foreign` so other packages depending on it will consider as native and won't attempt to pull the other architecture anymore.
- optional: increase its version number

  This will help to know when a new actual version was released and this should be done again.
- if the step before was done, then this step is mandatory: set the package as providing itself, versioned with the previous (actual) version

  ...to prevent the dependency issues from reappearing because of version rather than architecture.

There's no simple tool to do such change. Personally I edited directly the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file which is the database of all installed packages. A mistake there could damage the whole system installation. Below is a longer but safe method: download the binary package, unpack it, edit it as needed and repack it into an alternate binary package and then install this.

All should be done as user *root* (though [`fakeroot`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/fakeroot) could be used for the repackaging part as long as one understands how it's to be used: once).

```
mkdir /tmp/repack
cd /tmp/repack
apt-get download chromium:i386
dpkg-deb --raw-extract chromium_*_i386.deb chromium
```

edit the file `chromium/DEBIAN/control`:

- add (eg below the `Architecture: i386` entry) the `Multi-Arch:` entry:

  ```
  Multi-Arch: foreign
  ```
- edit the `Version:` entry

  Bump the version by appending a `.0` to it. For example today on Debian 12 it would then look like:

  ```
  Version: 119.0.6045.123-1~deb12u1.0
  ```
- edit the `Provides:` entry (on a package without it, add it):

  Append at the end of it `, chromium (= ACTUALVERSION)` with ACTUALVERSION replaced by the actual version without the `.0` appended. For example today on Debian 12 the line would look like:

  ```
  Provides: gnome-www-browser, www-browser, chromium (= 119.0.6045.123-1~deb12u1)
  ```

Repack the changed package into a new `.deb` file:

```
dpkg-deb --build chromium/ chromium.deb
```

and reinstall it as (real) `root` user, possibly along additional packages (which should be pulled automatically on future upgrades made like this):

```
apt-get install ./chromium.deb chromium-l10n
```

If the version wasn't bumped, `--reinstall` might be needed.

This will have to be done again each time a new version will be made available by Debian. This should be detected when a future `apt upgrade` command will tell that `chromium:i386` will be kept instead of being upgraded.

---

Actually tested as written on Debian 12.

Comment: +1. The “Multi-Arch: foreign” solution is the only one of the two here that works; pinning doesn’t work (because `chromium-l10n` has a strong dependency on the native-arch `chromium`). Another possible solution would be to mark `chromium` as “Multi-Arch: allowed` and use `chromium:any` in the dependency, but I don’t think that would add any value.

Comment: Incidentally this whole situation might be a good enough reason to ask the Chromium packaging team to mark `chromium` as “Multi-Arch: foreign” in Debian itself. (The current maintainers are quite responsive.)

Comment: @StephenKitt the 1st part wasn't to solve anything, it was a safety measure (against `full-upgrade` for example). Now about marking various packages as foreign, would then require official support for this. I didn't want to clutter the answer, but I could already see that a sub-component of chromium dynamically loading libraries complains on stderr that it couldn't load some lib64 library (3d related, eg vulkan) when running the i386 variant, and when reverting to the amd64 variant might complain in reverse order. So I'm actually not sure packages so complex can have a guarantee.

Comment: (of course can't manage to display back this library error on stderr when I want to see it again to keep some trace)

Comment: If there’s a component that can’t load a library, that’s a dependency bug regardless of the M-A changes — the same error would occur with a plain `chromium:i386` installation (ignoring `chromium-l10n`). It can get complicated, but the Wine packages manage it (and they’re more complex than the Chromium packages),.so it can be done.